# .getJSON not working right in for loop

Tags: jquery, json, for-loop, asynchronous

beginner here.

I have the following code

```
$.getJSON('http://uifaces.com/api/v1/random', function(uifaces){
                    var name=uifaces.username;
                    document.write(name)});
```

It runs fine but when I put it in a for loop, it's supposed to retrieve a different name every iteration but it outputs the same one every time.

I did some research and there were two suggestions I came across. One involves closures and the other involves queues. But neither this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
(function(i){
$myQueue.queue(function(next){
            $.getJSON('http://uifaces.com/api/v1/random', function(uifaces){
                    var name=uifaces.username;
                    document.write(name)});           
        next();
    });
})(i);
}
$myQueue.dequeue();
```

Nor this work. They just output the same names.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
(function(i){
$.getJSON('http://uifaces.com/api/v1/random', function(uifaces){
    var name=uifaces.username;
    document.write(name)
    }
    });
})(i);
```

}

I can't find any other suggestions on how to fix this. Any advice would help greatly.

Comment: You don't need closure or queue in this case, you're just erasing the name at each loop by doing `document.write(name);`.

Comment: I need to call it multiple times as the name is randomized with each call.

Comment: Holt, thanks for the response but if that was the case, it would output the name only once right? Here if my loop has 5 iterations, it gives me 5 of the same names.

Comment: @Holt is correct, you won't necessarily see the 5 names as they may all be returning in such short succession. Try replacing document.write with `$(document).html($(document).html() + name);` or if you know how to use the console try `console.log(name, 'a name')` and you'll see 5 different names

Comment: Oh, just saw your code edit. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX requests are cached by default in jQuery (except script and jsonp requests). When you are requesting the same resource over and over, it will only get it once, then serve the cached result the other times. That's why you get the same result over and over.

Use the `ajax` method, so that you can specify that caching should be off:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://uifaces.com/api/v1/random',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(uifaces){
      var name = uifaces.username;
      document.write(name);
    }
  });

}
```

Note: I only left the `document.write` in there for testing purposes, as it seems to work for you in your current situation. Normally you can't reliably use `document.write` like that; writing to the document after it has finished loading will open a new document that will replace the current.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you so much for the help! Also, thanks for the document.write tip. I wasn't sure it was the best way to test things but I didn't know how else to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

This  is a synchronicity issue. Instead of using getJSON, use the [$.ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that getJSON is based on. You can then specify the "async: false" parameter, which will wait for the server to return the proper name value for each iteration of the loop.